# Should I use Controller Argument or uri->segment?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Should use Controller Argument

```
function view($post_id) {
    ...
}
```

or uri->segment

```
function view() {
    ...
    $post_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    ...
}
```

Just for simple blog post ID. Is there a difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use the controller argument.

Then if you ever had to move the code and put it in a sub-directory it would still work, where as the segment method would not.

Comment: Agreed, uri segments come in handy but they're a huge pain in the ass when you realize you have to move something or rearrange the segments in some way. Use them where it makes sense, in this case the post variable makes more sense.

Comment: erm.... just reroute it to match the segment. i don't see what is so complicated here.

Comment: re-routing requires effort, using controller arguments means it just works

Answer (score 0):

**No**, there is no difference in this case. Use Controll Argument when you can. It allows you to mess more with routes and move the controller file.

If you wish to use uri, consider using `$this->uri->rsegment(3);` instead since it allows you to bind routes without it affecting the rsegment.

The best thing about CodeIgniter is that it's up to you which solution you prefer. I prefer using argument since it allows me to quickly understand how the values in the url affects the function without having to look through the function; I see the values at the top.

If you're afraid of creating error messages, consider setting it to

```
function view($post_id = NULL) {
    ...
}
```

instead. It will prevent errors if you access the url without a `post_id`.